# devise/activeadmin can't create user from admin panel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, activeadmin

I cannot create Users or Posts when logged into my Rails app's activeadmin panel. I've got a pretty straightforward custom Devise registrations controller handling signup:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    @user = User.new(sign_up_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        UserMailer.new_user(@user).deliver_now
        AdminMailer.new_user_waiting_for_approval(@user).deliver_now
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
        flash[:success] = "You're signed up! We'll notify you when your account has been approved."
      else
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def sign_up_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Here's my AdminUser model:

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  after_create { |admin| admin.send_reset_password_instructions }
  def password_required?
    new_record? ? false : super
  end
end
```

When I hit save, the page reloads with entered data still intact. Console readout is:

```
Started POST "/admin/users" for ::1 at 2017-03-21 09:25:22 -0700
Processing by Admin::UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LpGfS1Y+241vEIRQ+TW78SzM/+J7GnjRHAyt7Ll0ez4WYWc60/HpODJOsVg0spmpd1haTpSiNxQHOJfZlMh+sA==", "user"=>{"email"=>"j@h.com", "encrypted_password"=>"[FILTERED]", "reset_password_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "reset_password_sent_at(1i)"=>"[FILTERED]", "reset_password_sent_at(2i)"=>"[FILTERED]", "reset_password_sent_at(3i)"=>"[FILTERED]", "reset_password_sent_at(4i)"=>"[FILTERED]", "reset_password_sent_at(5i)"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_created_at(1i)"=>"", "remember_created_at(2i)"=>"", "remember_created_at(3i)"=>"", "remember_created_at(4i)"=>"", "remember_created_at(5i)"=>"", "current_sign_in_at(1i)"=>"", "current_sign_in_at(2i)"=>"", "current_sign_in_at(3i)"=>"", "current_sign_in_at(4i)"=>"", "current_sign_in_at(5i)"=>"", "last_sign_in_at(1i)"=>"", "last_sign_in_at(2i)"=>"", "last_sign_in_at(3i)"=>"", "last_sign_in_at(4i)"=>"", "last_sign_in_at(5i)"=>"", "current_sign_in_ip"=>"", "last_sign_in_ip"=>"", "firstname"=>"a", "lastname"=>"b", "provider"=>"", "uid"=>"", "oauth_token"=>"", "approved"=>"0", "website"=>"i.com", "is_admin"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
Unpermitted parameters: encrypted_password, reset_password_token, reset_password_sent_at(1i), reset_password_sent_at(2i), reset_password_sent_at(3i), reset_password_sent_at(4i), reset_password_sent_at(5i), remember_created_at(1i), remember_created_at(2i), remember_created_at(3i), remember_created_at(4i), remember_created_at(5i), current_sign_in_at(1i), current_sign_in_at(2i), current_sign_in_at(3i), current_sign_in_at(4i), current_sign_in_at(5i), last_sign_in_at(1i), last_sign_in_at(2i), last_sign_in_at(3i), last_sign_in_at(4i), last_sign_in_at(5i), current_sign_in_ip, last_sign_in_ip, provider, uid, oauth_token
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'j@h.com' LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'j@h.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  AdminUser Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Rendered /Users/mkeable/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-85ab3f5961e1/app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb (297.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 312ms (Views: 304.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
```

Why do I get two `User Exists`? Am certain the User doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you get any solution on this ? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @JulesCorb nope. i fixed it somehow, but the only thing i can remember is that i scrapped the separate `AdminUser` class depicted here in favor of a `User` class with an `admin` boolean.